# ValueError: Bad Input Shape while fitting Logistic Regression Model

Tags: python, logistic-regression

I am currently learning about logistic regression from scratch. I am creating a Logistic Regression model based on an altered form of the Iris Dataset I made. Here is an extract of my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

df = pd.read_excel('Iris_Dataset.xlsx')
df = df.dropna()

colour = pd.get_dummies(df.colour, drop_first = True)
species = pd.get_dummies(df.species, drop_first = True)
df = pd.concat([df, colour, species], axis = 1)
df = df.drop(['colour', 'species'], axis = 1)

x = df.drop(["versicolor", "virginica"], axis = 1)
y = pd.concat([df.versicolor, df.virginica], axis = 1)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 1)

model = LogisticRegression()

model.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

For some reason, at the last statement(model.fit(x_train, y_train)), I am getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-0c77380c6ea5> in <module>()
     18 model = LogisticRegression()
     19 
---> 20 model.fit(x_train, y_train)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in column_or_1d(y, warn)
    795         return np.ravel(y)
    796 
--> 797     raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
    798 
    799 

ValueError: bad input shape (86, 2)
```

I am not able to understand what the error means, nor why I am getting this error, no matter what I try. Please help me with this.

Here is the dataset, by the way. It is in the form of a google sheet but I have the same dataset copy-pasted as an Iris_Dataset.xlsx in Microsoft Excel (I couldn't figure out how to share the excel file directly):
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18zkZvPQ5q_ExaWu4dywsHtpO9D6ECdmXzvZahPryiqU/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** So I tried something else, this time I only converted the colour column into dummy values and left species intact. Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

df = pd.read_excel('Iris_Dataset.xlsx')
df = df.dropna()

colour = pd.get_dummies(df.colour, drop_first = True)
df = pd.concat([df, colour], axis = 1)
df = df.drop(['colour'], axis = 1)
    
x = df.drop(["species"], axis = 1)
y = df.species

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 1)
    
model = LogisticRegression()

model.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

The only reason I did it just for colours is that when I tried the same with no dummy values (I tried to pass just the column 'species' as a whole instead of what I did before), is that I got the error: `could not convert string to float: 'violet'`

So after executing the above code, I got the output, but the fitting process gave a warning message along with the output:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_logistic.py:940: ConvergenceWarning: lbfgs failed to converge (status=1):
STOP: TOTAL NO. of ITERATIONS REACHED LIMIT.

Increase the number of iterations (max_iter) or scale the data as shown in:
    https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html
Please also refer to the documentation for alternative solver options:
    https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#logistic-regression
  extra_warning_msg=_LOGISTIC_SOLVER_CONVERGENCE_MSG)
LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
                   intercept_scaling=1, l1_ratio=None, max_iter=100,
                   multi_class='auto', n_jobs=None, penalty='l2',
                   random_state=None, solver='lbfgs', tol=0.0001, verbose=0,
                   warm_start=False)
```

The rest of the code following that was somewhat smooth though, but I would like to know what the message means, or is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: Logistic regression cannot handle multiple outputs, use other classifiers like decision trees

Comment: @PrakashDahal I've actually seen other people use multiple outputs with Logistic Regression, but I couldn't understand why it worked for them and not for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inputting a dataframe with two columns `y` as your target vector in `LogisticRegression.fit()`, which is not possible. The target vector is required to be in the shape (n_samples,), being a sinlge column in dataframe terms.

Here's an example from the documentation:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
clf = LogisticRegression(random_state=0).fit(X, y)
clf.predict(X[:2, :])

clf.predict_proba(X[:2, :])


clf.score(X, y)
```

Print `y` and you will see it's a 1D array.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html

Comment: Is there a way by  which we can Store it multi-variable?